# nginx custom log format to log header value when exists

Tags: nginx, logging, nginx-reverse-proxy

**environment setup**

I have nginx webserver and simple backend application. this backend app has custom response header in certain condition (for example: X-Real-Status) and it's running behind nginx as an upstream (reverse proxy). now i have this custom header value with $upstream_http_x_real_status in nginx configuration.

**my question is:** I have two log format as below:

```
log_format req_format '$uri $request_method $status $request_time $http_host $upstream_response_time';

log_format req_format_v2 '$uri $request_method $upstream_http_x_real_status $request_time $http_host $upstream_response_time';
```

I wanna merge these two log format to one, because my custom header (upstream_http_x_real_status) not set for some situations (hosting incident, runtime error and so on) and req_format_v2 print empty rather than status (which is status of response is 504 Bad Gateway for example). I wanna have something like this in nginx configuration:

```
# DANGER: obviously syntax error
# ------------------------------
$real_status = $upstream_http_x_real_status | $status
 
log_format new_req_format '$uri $request_method $real_status $request_time $http_host $upstream_response_time';
```

how to achieve this purpose?

Comment: try `log_format req_format_v3 '$uri $request_method $status $upstream_http_x_real_status $request_time $http_host $upstream_response_time';` since all has been added, a `|` letter is invalid in the configuration of nginx.

Comment: Just log them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's should be as simple as one [map](https://nginx.org/r/map):

```
map $upstream_http_x_real_status $real_status {
  # use $upstream... by default
  default "$upstream_http_x_real_status";
  # but if it's empty, just use $status
  "" "$status";
}

log_format new_req_format '$uri $request_method $real_status $request_time $http_host $upstream_response_time';
```